# Get ConnectionString from appsettings.json instead of being hardcoded in .NET Core 2.0 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, connection-string, appsettings

I have the following class in NET Core2.0 App.

```
// required when local database does not exist or was deleted
public class ToDoContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppContext>
{
    public AppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        return new AppContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

This is required in Core 2.0 with migration when Database does not exist and has to be created when you run *update-database*.
[Unable to create migrations after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782446/unable-to-create-migrations-after-upgrading-to-asp-net-core-2-0)

I would like not having ConnectionString in 2 places(here and in appsettings.json) but only in .json
so I have tried to replace

```
"Server=localhost;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

with

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString
```

but it's not working, I'm getting null value.

UPDATE 1:
Just to note that adding explicitly .json is not necessery in Core 2 so the problem is not with the file.
https://andrewlock.net/exploring-program-and-startup-in-asp-net-core-2-preview1-2/

UPDATE 2:
Also I am already using Configuration for sending ConnectionString from .json to Context:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
}
```

But I can not use this for *ToDoContextFactory* because it does not have Configuration, and *ToDoContextFactory* is used by migrations so the App is not running at all.

SOLUTION:
Based on answer from @JRB I made it work like this:

```
public AppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    string projectPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Split(new String[] { @"bin\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(projectPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    return new AppContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Comment: Don't know about the latest version, but in the earlier version you still had to add the `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)` to your `ConfigurationBuilder`. Have you done this? Are 'normal' Application Settings working?

Comment: In Core2.0 this is done automatically: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-program-and-startup-in-asp-net-core-2-preview1-2/

Comment: In Core2.0 you can use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` to get the base path, in case you can't do it in the startup as mention @borisdj: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/237

Comment: For those wondering where `SetBasePath` comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843367/how-to-setbasepath-in-configurationbuilder-in-core-2-0/46843572 and where `AddJsonFile` comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382481/why-visual-studio-tell-me-that-addjsonfile-method-is-not-define-in-configurati

Comment: Thank you!
I think you should post a separate answer with your solution instead of embedding it in your question.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

STEP 1: Include the following in OnConfiguring()

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
```

STEP 2: Create appsettings.json:

```
  {
    "ConnectionStrings": {       
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=YOURSERVERNAME; Database=YOURDATABASENAME; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"        
    } 
  }
```

STEP 3: Hard copy appsettings.json to the correct directory

```
  Hard copy appsettings.json.config to the directory specified in the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory directory. 
  Use your debugger to find out which directory that is.
```

Assumption: you have already included package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (get it from Nuget) in your project.

Comment: I would disagree! "Copy `appsettings.json`" with the connection string inside is as bad as stating the connection string in 2 places! Who will be in charge to keep it insync?

Comment: The background of the question where both myself and borisdj ran into, is that in .NET Core 2.0 System.Configuration is not there anymore and need to be replaced. To  make the answer as easy to follow by others I choose in Step 3 for the hard copy approach. But you are of course correct that in a real world scenario you will add "appsetting.json" to your project and set the "Copy to Output Directory" in the "General-Advanced" tab in the "Property Pages" to "Copy Always", after which manual copy actions should not be necessary anymore.

Comment: @JRB: I personally disagree about hiding part of the actual answer away in a comment, especially without a disclaimer that it'll need to be manually updated if ever changed.

Comment: If you'd like to get connection strings from custom section of your `appsettings.json` check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924899/804385

Comment: Where do I find OnConfiguring ?

Comment: @MC9000 in your DbContext file next to OnModelCreating

Comment: Which class contains OnConfiguring in Step 1?

Comment: This helped me in my Core 3 Console app after I could not get it to work in the services configuration. I kind of like it here anyway since it's the similar to where it is in the .Net Framework as well.

Answer (score 24):

In ASPNET Core you do it in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

where your connection is defined in `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "..."
  },
}
```

Example from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core)

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000395/get-connectionstring-from-appsettings-json I was not able to configure the connectionString in appsettings.json

Comment: What if I want to use the DbContext in a different project, for example when having a separate project for the DA-layer?

Answer (score 16):

There are a couple things missing, both from the solutions above and also from the Microsoft documentation.  If you follow the link to the GitHub repository linked from the documentation above, you'll find the real solution.

I think the confusion lies with the fact that the default templates that many people are using do *not* contain the default constructor for Startup, so people don't necessarily know where the injected Configuration is coming from.

So, in Startup.cs, add:

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 
 {
     Configuration = configuration;
 }
```

and then in ConfigureServices method add what other people have said...

```
services.AddDbContext<ChromeContext>(options =>                    
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
```

you also have to ensure that you've got your appsettings.json file created and have a connection strings section similar to this

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

Of course, you will have to edit that to reflect your configuration.

Things to keep in mind.  This was tested using Entity Framework Core 3 in a .Net Standard 2.1 project.
I needed to add the nuget packages for:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0 because that's what I'm using, and that's what is required to get access to the UseSqlServer.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I have been looking for this for hours now.

Comment: what is ChromeContext ?

Comment: I am getting error ,  using (var context = new pixelleContext())
            {
                return context.Specsheet.ToList();
            }

Comment: @rahularyansharma Maybe start your own question and put a link to this one?  That way you can be a bit more thorough with your code sample?  In context, your code snippet above is not very helpful.  In my sample, ChromeContext is the name of the database context

Comment: its solved for now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099089/what-changes-need-to-be-made-in-context-class-to-move-connection-string-into-app/68108901#68108901

Answer (score 12):

I understand this has been marked as answered but I ran into a bit of a problem when I was working on a project where I have my **EF Core Data Access Layer** in a .DLL Project separated from the rest of my project, API, Auth and Web and mostly will like my other projects to reference this Data project. And I don't want to want to come into the Data project to change connection strings everytime.

**STEP 1: Include this in the OnConfiguring Method**

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
           var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
           IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                **.SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))**
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: false)
                .Build();
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
      }
```

**NOTE: .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))**
This will negate or invalidate the need to copy the file to a directory as ASP.NET CORE is smart enough to pick the the right file. Also the environment specified will pick right file when the building for Release or Production, assuming the Prod environment file is selected.

STEP 2: Create appsettings.json

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {       
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=YOURSERVERNAME; Database=YOURDATABASENAME; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"        
}
```

}

**PLEASE: Referece: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration**

Comment: I am in the same situation as you and I tried this. However, ConfigurationBuilder does not have a method "SetBasePath". I suspect it's because I am using Standard for my DLL as opposed to Core.

Comment: Try Microsoft.Extensions.Configurations.Json Package.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using "top level statements", you can get your connection string as follows:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Answer (score 5):

How about passing it as dp injection into that class?
in ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

create class to hold json strings:

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public MyOptions()
    {

    }
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public string Option2 { get; set; }
}
```

Add strings to json file:

```
"option1": "somestring",
"option2": "someothersecretstring"
```

In classes that need these strings, pass in as constructor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
 private readonly MyOptions _options;

    public SomeClass(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;           
    }    

 public void UseStrings()
 {
   var option1 = _options.Option1;
    var option2 = _options.Option2;
 //code
 }
}
```

Comment: I don"t see how this solves the problem. Can you edit the answer and integrate your solution into the example from question.

Comment: @borisdj How can you not see that it offers a solution to the OP's problem?

Comment: @JohanHerstad I have tried your solution, a good idea but I think because IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppContext> is called at design time and not runtime you cannot inject IOptions into contructors, you see my question here that explains further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085500/injecting-env-conn-string-into-net-core-2-0-w-ef-core-dbcontext-in-different-cl

Comment: The code that does the creation of the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations` uses `Activator`, so it requires a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Yes, of course. I knew I've been exposed to it but I just couldn't understand that at the time and didn't have the time to really research it. I just know I had to also implement it at some time in the future, never forgot this problem. I love that you have taken the time to give an answer below so long after the first question was asked.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a default pattern that you can employ to achieve this result without having to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` and do any config file copying.

It is detailed in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation), which also discusses the other ways in which the framework will attempt to instantiate your `DbContext` at design time.

Specifically, you leverage a new hook, in this case a static method of the form `public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)`.  The documentation implies otherwise, but this method can live in whichever class houses your entry point ([see src](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/28a581535b6f84932eb41015472709fe1b1c6af4/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/AppServiceProviderFactory.cs#L104)).  Implementing this is part of the guidance in the [1.x to 2.x migration document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#update-main-method-in-programcs) and what's not completely obvious looking at the code is that the call to `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` is, among other things, connecting your configuration in the default pattern that new projects start with.  That's all you need to get the configuration to be used by the design time services like migrations.

Here's more detail on what's going on deep down in there:

While adding a migration, when the framework attempts to create your `DbContext`, it [first](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/592be3047f8cf30ecac89f6fd4eca376a2bcc331/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/DbContextOperations.cs#L127) adds any `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementations it finds to a collection of factory methods that can be used to create your context, then it gets your configured services via the static hook discussed earlier and [looks](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/592be3047f8cf30ecac89f6fd4eca376a2bcc331/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/DbContextOperations.cs#L149) for any context types registered with a `DbContextOptions` (which happens in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` when you use `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextPool`) and adds those factories.  Finally, it [looks](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/592be3047f8cf30ecac89f6fd4eca376a2bcc331/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/DbContextOperations.cs#L161) through the assembly for any `DbContext` derived classes and creates a factory method that just calls `Activator.CreateInstance` as a final hail mary.

The order of precedence that the framework uses is the same as above.  Thus, if you have `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implemented, it will override the hook mentioned above.  For most common scenarios though, you won't need `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

Comment: It won't work if I have `DbContext` in a separate project.

Answer (score 4):

```
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        string conStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb1");
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in ASP.NET Core 2 by defining the connection string in your `appSettings.json` file. Then in your `Startup.cs` you specify which connection string to use.

`appSettings.json`

```
{
    "connectionStrings": {
        "YourDBConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDB;Trusted_Connection=True"
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set;}

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:YourDBConnectionString"];
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
string connectionString =
     builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDBConnectionString");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following code into `startup.cs` file.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       string con = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection");
       services.AddMvc();
       GlobalProperties.DBConnection = con;//DBConnection is a user defined static property of GlobalProperties class
   }
   ```
2. Use `GlobalProperties.DBConnection` property in `Context` class.

   ```
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {  
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GlobalProperties.DBConnection);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fancy I known but you could use a callback class, create a hostbuilder and set the configuration to a static property.

For asp core 2.2:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

namespace Project
{
    sealed class Program
    {
        #region Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// Last loaded configuration
        /// </summary>
        private static IConfiguration _Configuration;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Default application configuration
        /// </summary>
        internal static IConfiguration Configuration
        {
            get
            {
                // None configuration yet?
                if (Program._Configuration == null)
                {
                    // Create the builder using a callback class
                    IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<CallBackConfiguration>();

                    // Build everything but do not initialize it
                    builder.Build();
                }

                // Current configuration
                return Program._Configuration;
            }

            // Update configuration
            set => Program._Configuration = value;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public
        /// <summary>
        /// Start the webapp
        /// </summary>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the builder using the default Startup class
            IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();

            // Build everything and run it
            using (IWebHost host = builder.Build())
                host.Run();
        }
        #endregion


        #region CallBackConfiguration
        /// <summary>
        /// Aux class to callback configuration
        /// </summary>
        private class CallBackConfiguration
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Callback with configuration
            /// </summary>
            public CallBackConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                // Update the last configuration
                Program.Configuration = configuration;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Do nothing, just for compatibility
            /// </summary>
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                //
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

So now on you just use the static *Program.Configuration* at any other class you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need in different Layer :

Create a Static Class and expose all config properties on that layer as below :

```js
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace Core.DAL
{
    public static class ConfigSettings
    {
        public static string conStr1 { get ; }
        static ConfigSettings()
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(path, false);
            conStr1 = configurationBuilder.Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ConStr1").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extension:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static IDictionary<string, string> GetAllConnectionStrings(this IConfiguration obj)
  {
     var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     var section = obj.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetChildren();
     foreach (var cnn in section)
     {
        dic.Add(cnn.Key, cnn.Value);
     }
     return dic;
  }
}
```

Use:

```
var cnns = builder.Configuration.GetAllConnectionStrings();
```