# How to read appsettings.json in context in another project? Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to use the same `ConnectionString` in two places. In my web project `Insig.Api` which contains `ConnectionString` from `appsettings.json` and in another project class library `Insing.Infrastructure` where is my db context.

Insig.Api - Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddDbContext<InsigContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
    }
```

Insig.Infrastructure - InsigContext.cs

```
public class InsigContext : DbContext, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<InsigContext>
{
    public InsigContext() { }

    public InsigContext(DbContextOptions<InsigContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }

    public InsigContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {    
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<InsigContext>();    

        builder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InsigDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
   // Here I would like to use ConnectionString instead of raw string.    

        return new InsigContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

As you can see `ConnectionString` is needed in context as well because of Migrations (from Code First approach).

---

EDIT - code below doesn't work. When I'm trying to `Add-Migration Init` then I receives an error: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString`

```
public class InsigContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;    

        public InsigContext(DbContextOptions<InsigContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
        }

        public InsigContext() { }

        public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `IConfiguration` to your `InsigContext` constructor and use that to get the connection string

```
private readonly string connectionString;
public InsigContext(DbContextOptions<InsigContext> options,IConfiguration configuration)
                                                                          : base(options)
{ 
   this.connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection")
                                     .Value;
}
// you can use this.connectionString now
```

`IConfiguration` is defined in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace. So you probably want to add a reference to that in your class libarary.

If you want access to the `IConfiguration` object in another method, create a local variable and set that in your constructor

```
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
public InsigContext(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

public void CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
   // you can use this.configuration here as needed or get conn string
}
```

No need of multiple constructors. Keep one constructor where you are injecting the dependencies you want.

Comment: You can use `this.connectionString` inside that method

Comment: I had same idea, but check method `CreateDbContext` which actually use this constructor to create new object. And what am I suppose to pass then?

Comment: Not sure why you want to manually create an object / what you are trying to do. But you can always create a private variable in your class of type `IConfiguration` and use that in your `CreateDbContext`

Comment: Please check my Edit. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry! I did not explicitly mention it, You do not need 2 constructors. Merge it into one.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter. Still doesn't work. Maybe injection for `IConfiguration` doesn't work when it's different project.

Comment: It does work. Are you getting `null` on the constructor ? As i said, remove the unnecessary constructors. Keep one single constructor where you have all your dependencies are injected into.

Comment: Well it's injected when I run application. But whilst creating migration via `Add-Migration Init` in console I have error: `Value cannot be null.` so maybe it won't work for migrations? If I remove empty constructor then in console is information: `Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<InsigContext>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171879/discussion-between-dipix-and-shyju).

Comment: Was this ever resolved? The link in the discussion no longer works.

Comment: Dependency Injection will not work with IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to provide additional information [for my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555412/how-to-read-appsettings-json-in-context-in-another-project-asp-net-core#comment99910776_50555468).

Like the author, I faced the same issue to pass connection string to Data project from API project. I decided to specify global settings with connection string and linked them to both projects. I went step by step [through this article](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/). In result I've managed to use connection string in two places.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a folder name "Settings" in your data access layer project and create static AppSettings class inside that folder with a static string property name "ConnectionString" like below:

```
    public static class AppSettings
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Then add connectionstring to your appsettings.json file:

```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "ConString": "Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;uid=sa;pwd=12345;"
      }
    }
```

3. Add the statement below into your Startup() method in Startup.cs class in your UI layer to get the connection string:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            AppSettings.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["ConString"];
        }
    
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(option => 
                option.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.ConnectionString));
        }
    }
```

That's all! Now whenever you want to use your connectionstring just call AppSettings.ConnectionString and it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You should inject the IConfiguration interface in your other project using dependency injection. Like this:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public InsigContext(IConfiguration config) {
    _config = config;
}
```

Then u can use the `_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");`method to get the connection string.

Comment: If I understood correctly, author needs to provide connection string into Data layer project for case when he manipulates migrations and updating database directly within Data layer project bypassing ASP.Net Core project.
It happens when developer write command `dotnet ef database info` or `dotnet ef dbcontext info` in PowerShell, for example. [So DI doesn't work in this way.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1490#issuecomment-497013983)