# Why does the connection string in Startup interfere with EF Core migration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I want to add migrations to the project, so I've implemented the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface to it.

I've placed the `ContextFactory` in the presentation layer of the project, where the context is in de database layer.

In the start up I inject the contexts connection string like this:

```
services.AddTransient<FooDbContext>().AddDbContext<FooDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOODB_CONNECTIONSTRING")));
```

The `ContextFactory` (for migration is implemented like this):

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<FooDbContext>
{
    public WegisterDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FooDbContext>();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new FooDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

So if I comment out the injection in the startup, I'm able to run the migration, but with this code active, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)   at Wegister.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__7_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\Daphne\Source\Repos\SalomeCodes\Wegister\Wegister\Wegister\Startup.cs:line 66   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0(IServiceProvider p)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)  > at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__10`1.<AddCoreServices>b__10_1(IServiceProvider p)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

So the dependency injection overrides this connection string - but why?

What is the solution so I'm still possible to run code and migrate? Because when I start the code with the dependency injection on the connection string the application doesn't know where to connect with?

Comment: Have you checked that `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` returns not null string?

Comment: Yes it is set, although I can't set the appsettings.json variables at runtime right? so docker run --env DefaultConnection=foo.nletc isn't going to work right? So actually I want to be possible to set the string dynamically.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way than this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085500/injecting-env-conn-string-into-net-core-2-0-w-ef-core-dbcontext-in-different-cl ?

Comment: Can you share appsettings.json

Comment: Yes but it's not in the appsettings.json it works if i remove the dependency injection in my Startup where I also add the connectionstring.

Comment: @SaloméCodes if you have added environment variables as configuration provider after config files ( or using [default one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration)), then `docker run --env`  should work. As for example you've provided, `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` there used in separate assembly, not the one containing `Startup` as far as I understand.

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks! this was just a lack of knowledge.. sorry. I also read that launchsettings.json are just for visual studio. So I can set my environment variables in Appsettings.json with the `docker run --env` command?

Comment: 1) `launchsettings.json` are for development environments (VS and Rider supports it) 2) no, it will not set anything in `appsettings.json` you can add environment variables with `.AddEnvironmentVariables();` if you call it after `AddJsonFile` then existing anv vars will be used "overriding" what is written in json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this piece of code in the start up:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

var connstring = Configuration["WEGISTERDB_CONNECTIONSTRING"] ?? configuration.GetConnectionString("WEGISTERDB_CONNECTIONSTRING");
```

It made it possible to remove the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` as well..
Somehow migrations need a connectionstring which is already set, because it can't get connectionstrings as environment variable.