# What changes need to be made in context class to move connection string into appsettings.json file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .NET CORE WEB API project and I am trying to move my connection string to appsettings.json file.

for that I made following changes :

In start up file :

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(allowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
            services.AddDbContext<pixelleContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PixelleConnection")));
        }
```

and In appsettings.json file as follow :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PixelleConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=PixelleSpecSheets;Trusted_Connection=True;"    
  }
}
```

I am not sure what changes I need to do in my context class, context class as follow :

```
public partial class pixelleContext : DbContext
    {
        public pixelleContext()
        {
        }

        public pixelleContext(DbContextOptions<pixelleContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<SpecCol> SpecCol { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SpecRow> SpecRow { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Specsheet> Specsheet { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                

              
            }
        }
}
```

and code which throw error :

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Specsheet> Get()
        {
            using (var context = new pixelleContext())
            {
                return context.Specsheet.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything in your dbcontext class, it's right

You just should call the database like this:

```
    //....
    private readonly pixelleContext _context;

    public ****Controller(pixelleContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //....

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Specsheet> Get()
    {
        var model = _context.Specsheet.ToList();
        return model;
    }
```

[image]